# Lifting shared State up the tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a little React app that when a user selects a meat product the ui will show that category of meat from the json data file. I have a Products class as the parent to a class ProductCategoryRow and a SelectProduct function. I'm a little confused as to how to set the state in the Products class and pass the props on to ProductCategoryRow and SelectProduct.

```
function SelectProduct (props) {
const products = ['All', 'Beef', 'Lamb', 'Poultry'];
return (
<ul className='products'>
{products.map(function (prod) {
   return (
       <li
        style={prod === props.selectedProduct ? { color: '#d0021b' }:null}
                onClick={props.onSelect.bind(null, prod)}
                key={prod}>
                {prod}
            </li>
        )
    })}
</ul>
)};

class ProductCategoryRow extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
    list: list,
};
this.onDismiss = this.onDismiss.bind(this);
}

onDismiss(id) {
   const isNotId = item => item.objectID !== id;
   const updatedList = this.state.list.filter(isNotId);
   this.setState({ list: updatedList });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            { this.state.list.map(item => 
             <div key={item.objectID} className="product-category-row">
                        <div>{item.category}</div>
                        <div>{item.meatCut}</div>
                        <div>{item.cooking}</div>
                        <div>{item.price}</div>
                        <div>
                            <button
                            onClick={() => this.onDismiss(item.objectID)}
                            type="button"
                            >
                            Dismiss
                            </button>
                        </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
}

SelectProduct.propTypes = {
selectedProduct: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

class Products extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedProduct: 'All',
        lists: null
    };
    this.updateProduct = this.updateProduct.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount () {
  this.updateProduct(this.state.selectedProduct);
}

updateProduct(prod) {
    this.setState(function () {
        return {
            selectedProduct: prod,
            lists: null
        }
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <SelectProduct
            selectedProduct={this.state.selectedProduct}
            onSelect={this.updateProduct}
            />
            <ProductCategoryRow />
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Products;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you already have the updateProduct updating your state with the `prod` passed back from `SelectProduct`. You need to add `selectedProduct={this.state.selectedProduct}` as a prop to `ProductCategoryRow` and you should have access to the selected product. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the help unfortunately I am having a little trouble understanding how to pass a prop into another component. Can you please tell me exactly where to pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

You are already updating your parent component state when a product is selected, so that is good! Now, you need to pass in `this.state.selectedProduct` to the `ProductCategoryRow` component as a `selectedProduct` prop in your render method:

```
function SelectProduct (props) {
const products = ['All', 'Beef', 'Lamb', 'Poultry'];
return (
<ul className='products'>
{products.map(function (prod) {
   return (
       <li
        style={prod === props.selectedProduct ? { color: '#d0021b' }:null}
                onClick={props.onSelect.bind(null, prod)}
                key={prod}>
                {prod}
            </li>
        )
    })}
</ul>
)};

class ProductCategoryRow extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
    list: list,
};
this.onDismiss = this.onDismiss.bind(this);
}

onDismiss(id) {
   const isNotId = item => item.objectID !== id;
   const updatedList = this.state.list.filter(isNotId);
   this.setState({ list: updatedList });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            { this.state.list.map(item => 
             <div key={item.objectID} className="product-category-row">
                        <div>{item.category}</div>
                        <div>{item.meatCut}</div>
                        <div>{item.cooking}</div>
                        <div>{item.price}</div>
                        <div>
                            <button
                            onClick={() => this.onDismiss(item.objectID)}
                            type="button"
                            >
                            Dismiss
                            </button>
                        </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
}

SelectProduct.propTypes = {
selectedProduct: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

class Products extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedProduct: 'All',
        lists: null
    };
    this.updateProduct = this.updateProduct.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount () {
  this.updateProduct(this.state.selectedProduct);
}

updateProduct(prod) {
    this.setState(function () {
        return {
            selectedProduct: prod,
            lists: null
        }
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <SelectProduct
            selectedProduct={this.state.selectedProduct}
            onSelect={this.updateProduct}
            />
            <ProductCategoryRow selectedProduct={this.state.selectedProduct} />
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Products;
```

Comment: How do I get the onSelect={this.updateProduct} to only show the items that match {item.category} from ProductCategoryRow